# Are the ESLint globals from all environments "es6", "es2017", and "es2020" cumulative or incremental settings?

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

ESLint has global settings from all environments:

```json
{
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "es2017": true,
        "es2020": true
    }
}
```

Are the ESLint globals from all environments `es6`, `es2017`, and `es2020` cumulative or incremental settings? In other words, is it enough to enable `es2020` support to benefit from `es6` and `es2017` as well, or it is mandatory to enable each JS language version support separately?

Comment: Well, what happens if you enable only the latest and use earlier globals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the environments are cumulative.

This can be best seen by looking at the [relevant part of the source code](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/183e3006841c29efdd245c45a72e6cefac86ae35/conf/environments.js#L58-L81) (linking to the current master version on GitHub).

`es6` includes only the globals defined in `newGlobals2015`. `es2017` includes `newGlobals2015` and `newGlobals2017`, while `es2020` includes `newGlobals2015`, `newGlobals2017` and `newGlobals2020`.

**Update**

Newer versions of ESLint depend on environments defined in a [separate package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globals#readme), which uses a different structure (it's a plain JSON file). In the end though, the global definitions haven't changed.