# How to check worker script with eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint, web-worker

ESlint seems to not catch obvious errors in a worker script.

In `.eslintrc.json`, there is:

```
"env": {
    "es2020": true,
    "browser": false,
    "worker": false,
    "node": false
},
```

Browser, Worker and Node are all set to false, to deffer the environment specification on a per script basis.

If at the top of a script to be run in the usual browser environment, I add `/* eslint-env browser */`, it works as expected. However, if at the top of a script to be run as a Worker, I add `/* eslint-env worker */`, unfortunately obvious errors are not caught at all.

Example:

```
/* eslint-env worker */
const p = document.createElement('p');
p.textContent = 'Test.';
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

ESlint does not trigger an error about `document` which is not available in a Worker environment.

What is the proper way to specify an environment, either Browser or Worker, on a per file basis?

— Update: more investigations —

After “ [Are the ESLint globals from all environments …](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61688206/are-the-eslint-globals-from-all-environments-es6-es2017-and-es2020-cumul) ” , if from `node` I do:

```
const globals = require('globals');
```

Then

```
console.log(globals.browser);
```

I see `document` as a global object.

Then

```
console.log(globals.worker);
```

I don’t see `document` anymore as a global object.

The globals définitions are correct, but for some reason, not properly applied or checked.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a workaround than the expected answer.

First, [`@dropbox/eslint-plugin-service-worker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dropbox/eslint-plugin-service-worker) is to be installed. Then, in `.eslintrc.json`. Then, under then `"plugins"` section, `"@dropbox/service-worker"` is added and also under the `"rules"` section, `"@dropbox/service-worker/no-restricted-web-api": ["error"]` is added (the same for `no-deprecated-extension-api` and `no-dynamic-import`).

The caveats is that the rules are checked whatever the `/* eslint-env xxx */` is. This means there must be a command to check scripts whose context is the browser environment and a another command to check scripts whose context is the web worker environment. In clearer words: two configuration files are needed, so different run of `eslint`, since the environment cannot be selected on a file basis, unlike what it looks like.

Not a good enough solution, however a usable workaround at least.